# WooCommerce Orders with Custom status change status Cancelled after failed payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, status, orders

I use a custom status: *Payment Due*. Once an order gets the status *Payment Due* it will automatically trigger a email after 14 days reminding the customer to pay for their order.
Now when this customer tries to pay but it fails for whatever reason the order will get the status *Cancelled*.
But I need this order to get back to status *Payment Due* or *something similar like Payment Failed*.

So for particular statuses I would really like to remove the status **Cancelled** and **Failed** from applying when a customer fails to complete the payment and apply a other *custom status* in stead

Answer (score 0):

The following hook did the trick:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_reminder_to_failed', 
'change_status_to_payment_required' , 10, 10 );

function change_status_to_payment_required( $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$order->update_status( 'payment-required' );
}
```